# segmentation-fault with boost::polygon

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, polygon, boost-polygon

I have got polygon-data which I processed. Now I want to see how well my processed data fits my original data. For this task I want to use BOOST's polygon set-operators.
The following code gives me a segfault though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>

using namespace boost::polygon::operators;
using namespace std;

typedef boost::polygon::polygon_data<double> BPolygon;
typedef boost::polygon::polygon_traits<BPolygon>::point_type BPoint;
typedef boost::polygon::polygon_set_data<double> BPolygonSet;
typedef std::vector<BPolygon> BPolygonVec;


double meassureError(BPolygonVec &polys1, BPolygonVec &polys2)
{
  BPolygonSet set1;
  BPolygonSet set2;

  assign(set1, polys1);
  assign(set2, polys2);

  return area(set1 ^ set2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  BPolygonVec polys1;
  BPolygonVec polys2;

  loadPolysFromFile(polys1);
  loadPolysFromFile(polys2);

  cout << meassureError(polys1, polys2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

gdb-output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08156ce7 in std::list<boost::polygon::point_data<double>, std::allocator<boost::polygon::point_data<double> > >::begin (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:759
759           { return iterator(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next); }
```

My data consists of about 2000 polygons with roughly 10 vertices each and I would expect to have enough memory in order to process that. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that boost::polygon is a different library than boost::geometry, used in your question-tag-list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm

> The coordinate data type is a template parameter of all data types and
>   algorithms provided by the library, and is expected to be integral.
>   Floating point coordinate data types are not supported by the
>   algorithms implemented in the library due to the fact that the
>   achieving floating point robustness implies a different set of
>   algorithms and generally platform specific assumptions about floating
>   point representations.