# check polygon features in boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I recently tried to work on boost::geometry library. I found the code below

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main(void)
{
    typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    //! create a polygon
    polygon p;
    p.outer().push_back(point(0., 0.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(1., 0.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(1., 2.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(2., 3.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(0., 4.));

    //! display it
    std::cout << "generated polygon:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << bg::wkt<polygon>(p) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea for checking:

1. Is it a simple polygon?
2. What is the orientation (clockwise, counterclockwise)
3. Is it closed?

By the way, I am using boost version 1.53.0.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of [**`Polygon`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_polygon.html) in BG explains most high level decisions:

> A polygon is A polygon is a planar surface defined by ***one exterior boundary and zero or more interior boundaries*** (OGC Simple Feature Specification).
>
> So the definition of a Boost.Geometry polygon differs a bit from e.g. Wiki, where a polygon does not have holes. A polygon of Boost.Geometry is a polygon with or without holes. (A polygon without holes is a helper geometry within Boost.Geometry, and referred to as a ***ring***.)

Under [**`Ring`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_ring.html) we find:

> - there might be a specialization of `traits::point_order` defining the order or orientation of its points, `clockwise` or `counterclockwise`
> - there might be a specialization of `traits::closure` defining the closure, `open` or `closed`

Under **`Rules`** you will find most answers to your questions:

> Besides the Concepts, which are checks on compile-time, there are some other rules that valid polygons must fulfill. This follows the opengeospatial rules (see link above).
>
> - Polygons are ***simple geometric objects*** (See also wiki but holes are allowed in Boost.Geometry polygons).
> - If the polygons underlying ring_type is defined as clockwise, the exterior ring must have the clockwise orientation, and any interior ring must be reversed w.r.t. the defined orientation (so: counter clockwise for clockwise exterior rings). If the ring_type is defined counter clockwise, it is vice versa.
> - If the polygons underlying ring_type is defined as closed, all rings must be closed: the first point must be spatially equal to the last point.
> - The interior is a connected point set.
> - There should be no self intersections, but self tangencies (between exterior/interior rings) are allowed (as long as the interior is a connected point set.
> - There should be no cut lines, spikes or punctures.
> - The interior rings should be located within the exterior ring. Interior rings may not be located within each other.

---

Note that

1. you can use **[`boost::geometry::correct`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/correct.html)** to correct a ring/polygon that doesn't adhere to all requirements above.
2. Boost 1.56.0 added **[`boost::geometry::is_valid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/is_valid.html)** so you can verify validity of a geometry. For older versions, see e.g. **[polygons union using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321915/polygons-union-using-boost/22324995#22324995)**