# Boost, geometry

Tags: c++, boost, intersection, boost-geometry

I have a problem with boost::geomentry.

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main(){
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> TBoostPoint;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<TBoostPoint> TBoostPoly;    
TBoostPoly square, square1;    
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(0.5,4.25));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(0.5,4.5));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(1.0,4.5));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(1.0,4.25));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(0.5,4.25));    
const double eps[] = {1e-15,1e-15,2e-15,2e-15};    
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(0.5,4.25 + eps[0]));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(0.5,4.5  + eps[1]));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(1.0,4.5  + eps[2]));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(1.0,4.25 + eps[3]));
square.outer().push_back(TBoostPoint(0.5,4.25 + eps[0]));    
boost::geometry::correct(square);
boost::geometry::correct(square1);    
std::vector<TBoostPoly> output;    
boost::geometry::intersection(square,square1,output);    
return 0;    
}
```

If I use Boost(*1_58*) output - is not correct, but if I use Boost(*1_55* or *1_52*), output - is correct.

---

---

**Expected**

```
{(0.5,4.25),(0.5,4.5),(1.0,4.25),(1.0,4.25),(0.5,4.25)}
```

**Result (boost *1_58*)**

```
{(0.5,4.25),(0.5,4.5),(1.0,4.25),(1.0,4.25 + 5e-8),(0.5,4.25)}.
```

Comment: Might care to add what you'd expect (and what you get). Not all of us have "ancient" Boost installations

Comment: You should use integral values. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080868/segmentation-fault-with-boostpolygon/20081230#20081230

Comment: Did you mean square1 there (the eps-ed poly?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use integral coordinates.

From the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm

> The coordinate data type is a template parameter of all data types and
>   algorithms provided by the library, and is expected to be integral.
>   Floating point coordinate data types are not supported by the
>   algorithms implemented in the library due to the fact that the
>   achieving floating point robustness implies a different set of
>   algorithms and generally platform specific assumptions about floating
>   point representations.

Same applies to earlier versions.

In your case the output of Boost(1_55 or 1_52) is correct (**by accident**).

Comment: ＋1 for addressing the essence. My answer was just curiosity. This is the answer to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

The output may seem correct the first around, but in fact it isn't if you look closer:

A slightly refactored sample: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c54799c6c5ed4f5d)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type>
    void append(C& container, std::initializer_list<T> init) {
        container.insert(container.end(), init);
    }

int main() {
    typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> TBoostPoint;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<TBoostPoint> TBoostPoly;

    std::vector<TBoostPoly> squares;

    using Eps = boost::array<double, 4>;

    for (auto const& eps : { 
                Eps {{     0,     0,     0,     0 }},
                Eps {{ 1e-15, 1e-15, 2e-15, 2e-15 }},
            })
    {
        TBoostPoly square;
        append(square.outer(), {
             { 0.5,  4.25 + eps[0] },
             { 0.5,   4.5 + eps[1] },
             { 1.0,   4.5 + eps[2] },
             { 1.0,  4.25 + eps[3] },
             { 0.5,  4.25 + eps[0] }
            });

        squares.push_back(std::move(square));
    }

    for (auto& p : squares)
        bg::correct(p);

    std::vector<TBoostPoly> output;
    bg::intersection(squares[0], squares[1], output);

    for (auto& p : output) std::cout << "Output: " << bg::wkt(p) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<bg::coordinate_type<TBoostPoint>::type >::max_digits10);
    for (auto& p : output) std::cout << "Output: " << bg::wkt(p) << "\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
Output: POLYGON((0.5 4.5,1 4.5,1 4.25,0.5 4.25,0.5 4.5))
Output: POLYGON((0.50000000000000000 4.50000000000000000,1.00000000000000000 4.50000000000000000,1.00000000000000000 4.25000000000000178,0.50000000000000000 4.25000004999999970,0.50000000000000000 4.50000000000000000))
```

As you can see, the naive, natural output **may** seem to be `4.25` at some point, but the actual value stored is `4.25000000000000178` at that exact moment.

Depending on what requirements you have you might be happier with some arbitrary precision decimal representation types. As a proof of concept, here's the same program parameterized to use 50-digit decimal floats:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2312a3287fbf819f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bmp = boost::multiprecision;

template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type>
    void append(C& container, std::initializer_list<T> init) {
        container.insert(container.end(), init);
    }

int main() {
    typedef bmp::number<bmp::cpp_dec_float<50>, bmp::et_off> Decimal;
    typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<Decimal> TBoostPoint;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<TBoostPoint> TBoostPoly;

    std::vector<TBoostPoly> squares;

    using Eps = boost::array<Decimal, 4>;

    for (auto const& eps : { 
                Eps {{     0,     0,     0,     0 }},
                Eps {{ 1e-15, 1e-15, 2e-15, 2e-15 }},
            })
    {
        TBoostPoly square;
        append(square.outer(), {
             { 0.5,  4.25 + eps[0] },
             { 0.5,   4.5 + eps[1] },
             { 1.0,   4.5 + eps[2] },
             { 1.0,  4.25 + eps[3] },
             { 0.5,  4.25 + eps[0] }
            });

        squares.push_back(std::move(square));
    }

    for (auto& p : squares)
        bg::correct(p);

    std::vector<TBoostPoly> output;
    bg::intersection(squares[0], squares[1], output);

    for (auto& p : output) std::cout << "Output: " << bg::wkt(p) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<bg::coordinate_type<TBoostPoint>::type >::max_digits10);
    for (auto& p : output) std::cout << "Output: " << bg::wkt(p) << "\n";
}
```

Which prints:

```
Output: POLYGON((0.5 4.5,1 4.5,1 4.25,0.5 4.25,0.5 4.5))
Output: POLYGON((0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4.25000000000000200000000000000015541079975332215847661437120239003029098500000000,0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4.25000000000000100000000000000007770539987666107923830718560119501514549200000000,0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
```

Comment: I realize this answer doesn't add essential information beyond the existing answer. For the curious the Multiprecision example might be informative, though.